# Laptop freezes on Wireless Mouse Adapter attach/detach

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, freeze, wireless-mouse

I am using Microsoft Wireless Notebook Optical Mouse 3000 with Toshiba Satellite Pro P300-1CG. Recently I have installed Windows 7 64-bit. Now once in a while when I plug-in or plug-out wireless mouse adapter, the computer freezes (image stays on the screen, but the computer is not responsive). I have noticed that it mostly happens after I recover my computer from sleep mode. To continue using laptop I have to shut it down by pressing and holding power button for 7 seconds and then booting it up again.

What can be done to prevent this?

**Edit:** I have noticed that computer freezes even when I plug-in the mouse during booting Windows (mouse driver should not be loaded yet). I believe this is USB-power issue. How can I diagnose this?

**Edit:** I have bought new mouse, now with Bluetooth. Hopefully this one will not freeze my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had similar issues connecting/disconnecting a USB device that had damaged circuitry within it.  In my case, it was a TV Tuner that had been sitting in my closet for years and was killed by attempting to use a power cord of the wrong amperage and voltage.  Is it possible that something similar could be going on inside your mouse adapter?

Comment: No idea really. I am no specialist in hardware, so I don't think that would be a good idea to open adapter case at all. Nevertheless, that's best answer so far...

Answer (score 1):

You say that you do not require any drivers for the mouse because it is a Microsoft device, however I think that you should always have the latest drivers installed (providing they are stable).  If the current drivers are causing the instability, which may not be the case, then new drivers could fix this problem.  You can fetch them [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/F/9/8F922E4F-95E3-4F50-9801-7C2561F75AB3/IPx64_1033_7.10.344.0.exe).  After installing, make sure to restart your computer for the new drivers to take effect.

Let me know how this turns out.

Comment: Have installed it successfully. I will tell you my experience for the next few days. Hope it have fixed the problem. P.S. Welcome to Super User :)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. Computer frozen today with up-to-date driver.

Comment: Was it working for a few days and then stopped working again?  If you can go into the device manager and check what driver version is being used that would be helpful for diagnosis.  Chances are that it is using the older version of the driver.

The other case is that it is a power issue.  Have you tried using other ports?